# Flutter - Firebase push notification using firebase messaging success but not get notification

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just try using firebase push notification and messaging. I got an issue which is when I tried send message via console it showed completed but I do not get the notification. So can you guys explain my coding mistake. What must I do?

Local notification was fine.
**local notification**
[image: local notification]

Here the message that I tried send on console but i dont get any notification on the phone.

**firebase console**
[image: firebase console]

this is my code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'firebase_options.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
    
    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
        importance: Importance.high,
        playSound: true);
    
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('A bg message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');
    }
    
    
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
            // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
            // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
            // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
            // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
            // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
            // is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
      // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
      // how it looks.
    
      // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
      // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
      // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
      // always marked "final".
    
      final String title;
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
    
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
              RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
              AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
              if (notification != null && android != null) {
                flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
                    notification.hashCode,
                    notification.title,
                    notification.body,
                    NotificationDetails(
                      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                        channel.id,
                        channel.name,
                        channelDescription : channel.description,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        playSound: true,
                        icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                      ),
                    ));
              }
        });
    
            FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
              print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
              RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
              AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
              if (notification != null && android != null) {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text(notification.title),
                        content: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [Text(notification.body)],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
            });
          }
    
      void showNotification() {
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
        });
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0,
            "Testing $_counter",
            "How you doin ?",
            NotificationDetails(
                android: AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name, channelDescription: channel.description,
                    importance: Importance.high,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    playSound: true,
                    icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher')));
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
        // by the _incrementCounter method above.
        //
        // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
        // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
        // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
            // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
            // in the middle of the parent.
            child: Column(
              // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
              // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
              // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
              //
              // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
              // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
              // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
              // to see the wireframe for each widget.
              //
              // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
              // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
              // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
              // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
              // horizontal).
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: showNotification,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    }
```

Is there any error on firebase connection to device?

***SOLVED***

Coding work fined.This occur because of I am using emulator instead of real device to tested.Thanks to u guys who answered my question.Those also help me a lot to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the below code

class name FCM

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> onBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  if (message.data.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final data = message.data['data'];
  }

  if (message.data.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final notification = message.data['notification'];
  }
  // Or do other work.
}

class FCM {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final streamCtlr = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  final titleCtlr = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  final bodyCtlr = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  setNotifications() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
          (message) async {
        if (message.data.containsKey('data')) {
          // Handle data message
          streamCtlr.sink.add(message.data['data']);
        }
        if (message.data.containsKey('notification')) {
          // Handle notification message
          streamCtlr.sink.add(message.data['notification']);
        }
        // Or do other work.
        titleCtlr.sink.add(message.notification!.title!);
        bodyCtlr.sink.add(message.notification!.body!);
      },
    );
    // With this token you can test it easily on your phone
    final token =
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) => print('Token: $value'));
  }

  dispose() {
    streamCtlr.close();
    bodyCtlr.close();
    titleCtlr.close();
  }
}
```

And Main Class

```
 void main() async {
  await init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future init() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String notificationTitle = 'No Title';
  String notificationBody = 'No Body';
  String notificationData = 'No Data';

  @override
  void initState() {
    final firebaseMessaging = FCM();
    firebaseMessaging.setNotifications();

    firebaseMessaging.streamCtlr.stream.listen(_changeData);
    firebaseMessaging.bodyCtlr.stream.listen(_changeBody);
    firebaseMessaging.titleCtlr.stream.listen(_changeTitle);

    super.initState();
  }

  _changeData(String msg) => setState(() => notificationData = msg);
  _changeBody(String msg) => setState(() => notificationBody = msg);
  _changeTitle(String msg) => setState(() => notificationTitle = msg);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              notificationTitle,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(
              notificationBody,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
            Text(
              notificationData,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: nothing come out..only show no title no body no data

Comment: Send some data in notification.

Comment: Do you mean I need to send from firebase console to device?

Comment: yes, You have to send something from FCM

Comment: I had but nothing happen.

Comment: Add a break point at setNotifications() and check if you able to listen the  "onMessage.listen" method  and one more thing , Are you sending the notification to correct device ?

Comment: ok I will try..how can I check is that correct device?Im using emulator.

Comment: Not sure in emulator, Please try in real device.

Comment: Just tested, working in real device.

Comment: Yeahhh thank you..Its because running on emulator I guess. It working fine on real one. Thanks a lot. Your answer also work fine.

Comment: Ok cool, Please vote up, will help others also.

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling _firebasebackgroundhanler function as below in code

```
    void main() async {
      final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
```

Firebasebackground handler function :

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
```

Comment: still the same.